# Ajax Asynchronous Request Performed Sequentially

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have the following code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.runner').click(function(){
            var row_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
            $('#' + row_id).html("<img src='loader.gif' />");
            //alert("URL: engine_worker.php?start_id=" + row_id);
            // Calls a script that duplicates PushEngine.php
            $.ajax({type:"GET", url:"engine_worker.php?start_id=" + row_id, success: function(text){
                $('#' + row_id).html("DONE");
                $('#' + row_id).parent().remove();
            },error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                // There's been an error
                alert( "NO! Error: " + $textStatus );
            }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The expected behavior would be that each time an element of the "runner" class is clicked the element with the given row_id will display an image as step one. This is working as intended. I would then expect that a GET request be set to the URL asynchronously in the background and upon completion would remove the row, or show an alert if the request fails. The HTML editing works as expected, the image is shown and the row is removed when the request completes. I can click on many rows, and each will display the image. However, if I click to rows that have similar expected response times, the time for them complete will be *t*2* and not simply *t*. The first row will be removed then after the expected time the second will be removed, giving the appearance of synchronous operations.
  Is there some reason this behavior is observed? Is the handling of the click events causing the second to wait for the first?

Comment: How would you expect it to work? As i read it, this is expected behaviour

Comment: $.ajax create different XMLHttpRequest, and each of them is an isolated ajax call to server.
i think that this "synchronous effect" is caused by your sequential click and by the browser's javascript engine. With google chrome you could trace the request a view that they aren't synchronous.

Comment: @Eomm I am not understanding you. Let's assume every call takes exactly 6 seconds. When I click the first, six seconds later it should disappear. If I click two, in six seconds the first should be removed and in 6.1 seconds the second, 0.1 seconds being the time it took me to click. Instead I am observing the first being removed in 6 seconds, and the second after 12.1 seconds (again, 0.1 seconds to click).

Comment: @A.Wolff See my comment to Eomm. If what I am seeing is the expected behavior it is not the intended behavior.

Comment: @MDavis No, that's not how it works. Usually server handles only one request at a time made by a single user. Otherwise, would be quite easy to do a DoS attack

Comment: @A.Wolff Want to submit that as an answer? Running some other tests and observing the server-status indicates you are correct. The answer to my question, "You can't sanely do this."

Answer (score 0):

The DOM elements that contain **runner** class aren't **a** html tags?. If so, maybe you need to add the method [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to your handler. Your code should look like this:

```
$('.runner').click(function(e){
        var row_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        $('#' + row_id).html("<img src='loader.gif' />");
        //alert("URL: engine_worker.php?start_id=" + row_id);
        // Calls a script that duplicates PushEngine.php
        $.ajax({type:"GET", url:"engine_worker.php?start_id=" + row_id, success: function(text){
            $('#' + row_id).html("DONE");
            $('#' + row_id).parent().remove();
        },error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // There's been an error
            alert( "NO! Error: " + $textStatus );
        }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: No, the elements are <td> or <span> elements. There should be default behavior to prevent when clicking them.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your event attachment with the following code:

```
$('#container-id').on('click', '.runner', function(){
    var row_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $('#' + row_id).html("<img src='loader.gif' />");
    //alert("URL: engine_worker.php?start_id=" + row_id);
    // Calls a script that duplicates PushEngine.php
    $.ajax({type:"GET", url:"engine_worker.php?start_id=" + row_id, success: function(text){
        $('#' + row_id).html("DONE");
        $('#' + row_id).parent().remove();
    },error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // There's been an error
        alert( "NO! Error: " + $textStatus );
    }
    });
});
```

Where **container-id** is the id of the closest container DOM element.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Does this address the issue brought up by A. Wolff in my question? In essence, I am trying to DoS my server. It looks like your suggestion would perform the same operations as mine, and have the same result. Handling the click is not the issue.